# Singular cohomology of singular complex variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex projective algebraic variety of (complex) dimension $n$, then we could consider the singular cohomology of it. I want to know what the top degree cohomology group $H^{2n}(X)$ is. If $X$ is smooth, then we know $X$ is a smooth closed orientable manifold, so by Poincare duality, we have $H^{2n}(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{0}(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$. However, when $X$ is singular, I know in general, Poincare duality does not hold in this case.

My question is, when $X$ is singular, is it true $H^{2n}(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$? If not, what could we say of $H^{2n}(X,\mathbb{Z})$?

I need to say I do not know algebraic topology very well and I only know basic things for topology. So maybe this question is obviously true or false. Hope you could explain it in more details. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, if your definition of a variety includes "irreducible."

Comment: @Kohan Thanks a lot. My variety is indeed irreducible. Could you tell me how to prove it?

Comment: It is a bit overkill, but one can derive this from (Hironaka's) resolution of singularities theorem: If $f: \tilde X\to X$ is a resolution then $\tilde X$ is a connected oriented manifold and $f$ is a homeomorphism away from the codimension 2 skeleta of a triangulations of $\tilde X, X$ and, therefore, induces an isomorphism of top-dimensional homology groups.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks a lot.